# spring boot and RDS db. Failed Conexion

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, amazon-rds

i not conection.

have db in RDS amazon and have app in spring boot with hibernate...

state db is public..

i have conexion in local with workwench mysql. but not with app..

HELP ME PLEASE!!

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-06-30 13:21:16.187  INFO 22852 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-30 13:21:16.195  INFO 22852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-30 13:21:16.198  WARN 22852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-06-30 13:21:17.960 ERROR 22852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'master'@'186.23.179.139' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8buA.png)

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://autofabricadb.clbpfrarz8ji.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbautofabrica

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I HAVE CONEXIONNN  BUT NOW SHOWW THE NEXT

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132) [mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) [mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted dependency(maven or gradle whatever you used to build the application) of mysql connector/jdbc driver for mysql, Make sure you've compatible version of jdbc mysql connector and your mysql version. Also keep in mind if your master user password and credentials maintained in your application properties file along with datasource url.